# What's the difference between `useCallback` with an empty array as inputs and `useCallback` without a second parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On my journey to try and understand React Hooks better I came across some behaviour I did not expect. I was attempting to create an array of refs and pushing to said array via an onRef function I would pass to my `<div>'s`. The array kept getting bigger everytime the component re-rendered presumably just because it was a simple arrow function and not memoized.

So then I added the `useCallback` hook to make sure that I wouldn't get the same ref multiple times, but to my surprise it still called the function every re-render. After adding an empty array as second parameter the refs only fired once per component as expected.

This behaviour is demonstrated in the snippet below.

```js
const Example = () => {
  const _refs = React.useRef([]);
  
  // Var to force a re-render.
  const [ forceCount, forceUpdate ] = React.useState(0);
  
  const onRef = (ref) => {
    if (ref && ref !== null) {
      console.log("Adding Ref -> Just an arrow function");
      _refs.current.push(ref);
    }
  }
  
  const onRefCallbackWithoutInputs = React.useCallback((ref) => {
    if (ref && ref !== null) {
      console.log("Adding Ref -> Callback without inputs.");
      _refs.current.push(ref);
    }
  });
  
  const onRefCallbackEmptyArray = React.useCallback((ref) => {
    if (ref && ref !== null) {
      console.log("Adding Ref -> Callback with empty array");
      _refs.current.push(ref);
    }
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Refs size: ", _refs.current.length);
  });
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={onRef}/>
      <div ref={onRefCallbackWithoutInputs}/>
      <div ref={onRefCallbackEmptyArray}/>
      <div onClick={() => forceUpdate(forceCount + 1)} 
        style = {
          {
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px',
            marginTop: '12px',
            backgroundColor: 'orange'
          }
        }>
        {'Click me to update'}
       </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

I assumed `useCallback` would have an empty array as a default for the second parameter. So what exactly does not giving a second parameter do? Why does it behave differently?

Comment: If you don't pass it an array as second argument, a new callback function will be created every render, just as `useEffect` with no second argument invokes the effect after every render.

Comment: So it's effectively no different than using a normal arrow function then?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: I'd like to add to this that it is considerably slower to to define an `useCallback` without params than to define a normal arrow function. I made a small benchmark where I created a million arrow functions and a million `useCallback` without params and it continuously was about 20 times slower to create than the arrow functions. Not that one would ever create so many but thought I'd add it.

Comment: Even with an empty array as the second argument, it's not always better in terms of performance as opposed to just using just the function. This is because you might be generating some overhead in terms of memory usage, which is not necessarily offset by the performance gain. See: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Answer (score 90, accepted):

For both `useMemo` and `useCallback` (which is essentially just a special case of `useMemo`), if the second argument is an empty array, the value will be memoized once and always returned.

If the second argument is omitted, the value will never be memoized, and the `useCallback` and the `useMemo` doesn't do anything.

Perhaps there's some edge case where you might conditionally memoize:

```
useMemo(someValue, shouldMemoize ? [] : null)
```

But in the vast majority of cases, the second argument to both `useMemo` and `useCallback` should be considered mandatory.  And in fact, the [Typescript definitions treat them this way](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e1f9647734bd990f49b0aca0f44acd4d55fe1e93/types/react/index.d.ts#L970).

```
// Require a second argument, and it must be an array
function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callback: T, deps: DependencyList): T;

// Second argument can be undefined, but must be explicitly passed as undefined, not omitted.
function useMemo<T>(factory: () => T, deps: DependencyList | undefined): T;
```

---

There's an [open pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/15025) that's enhancing the `exhaustive-deps` hooks eslint rule so that it will raise a lint error if the second argument is omitted, so pretty soon this will likely be a linter error.

Comment: Isn't this incorrect? The hooks docs for measuring a dom node (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) mention passing an empty parameter array to useCallback.

Comment: @tunesmith I don't see that that's contradicting anything in this answer: the answer is saying that "in the vast majority of cases you should pass an array as the second argument to `useCallback`", it doesn't say that there aren't cases where that array is empty.

Comment: Pull request was merged, I got this: `React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?`

Answer (score 18):

`useCallback` with an empty dependency array is a **memoized** function, which **does not compute updated states** (if you have states inside it, it'll use the initial value passed in `useState`.

When you want your `useCallback` function to **consume a state**, for example, you should pass it inside its dependency array, just like `useEffect` works! Doing this, your whole function will be **remounted** everytime that state changes.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's the same logic behind all the hooks, `useEffect`, `useLayoutEffect`, `useCallback`, `useMemo`, for dependency array,
if no dependencies passed means we passed the null value for dependencies, hence comparison would always result false and inline function will execute every time.

If empty dependencies are passed means there is nothing to compare further hence inline function will only execute once. (it is just like we are instructing React for no further comparison).

If the array are passed with some variable then it will compute the inline function based on the changes in the variable.

Though instance of the inline function will always created.