# How to pass down Callbacks with Arguments to React.memo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, memoization, arrow-functions

I was reading [this article](https://aheadcreative.co.uk/articles/avoiding-react-component-re-renders-with-react-memo/) on handling passing down callback functions to memoized React components (using `React.memo()`)

In order to not create a new function every single time the component re-renders, this article recommends to not make that function anonymous, but define it in the parent, and only then pass it down:

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const onHandleClick = useCallback(() => {
        // this will return the same function
        // instance between re-renders
    });

    return (
        <MemoizedSubComponent
            handleClick={onHandleClick}
        />
    );
}
```

This makes sense to me so far. However, in my case I need to pass down some arguments to my `handleClick()`, so later identify the component.

Until now, I have always solved this problem via arrow functions: So instead of `handleClick={onHandleClick}` I would normally do   `handleClick={()=> onHandleClick(i)}` - but doing this here would once again create a new function, correct? So I'd be at square 1 again.

How would I ideally solve this?

Edit:

So for example, say I want to do this:

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const onHandleClick = useCallback((itemIndex) => {
       console.log(itemIndex);
    });
    
    let data = [1,2,3,4]

    return (<div>
       {data.map(item => {
        return <MemoizedSubComponent
            handleClick={(i)=> onHandleClick(i)}
        />}
    </div>)
}
```

...but not recreate the arrow function on every single rerender.

Comment: Where would the `i` in `handleClick={()=> onHandleClick(i)}` come from?

Comment: and btw: [What's the difference between `useCallback` with an empty array as inputs and `useCallback` without a second parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55027723/6567275)

Comment: @Thomas let's say I'm looping over some data and create a `someData.map((item,i) => <MemoizedSubComponent handleClick={()=> onHandleClick(i)} item={item} />` on each iteration.

Comment: @Thomas thanks also for the link, so it seems like the example isn't actually using `useCallback` correctly!